# Как в Angularjs отобразить все данные из массива кроме данных из другого массива?

Tags: angularjs

Есть массив студентов. Студенты добавляются в группы.
При добавлении/удалении студентов есть 2 таблицы: студенты в группе и общий список студентов. На данный момент общий список студентов фиксированный.
Хочу сделать, что-б если я добавляю студента id-1 в группу он не отображался в общем списке,т.к. "нет смысла" добавлять его ещё раз.
Как в Angularjs отобразить все данные из массива кроме данных их другого массива?

Comment: а как бы Вы сделали это средствами Javascript? Причем здесь angularjs? Сравнивайте массивы: есть filter, map, forEach.

Comment: Сейчас отображаются из массива с помощью ангуляра. Я думаю фильтр поставить, но не знаю, как его прикрутить

Comment: не нужно лезть в дебри фильтров ангуляра. Фильтруйте в контроллере - будет тот же эффект. Наводить красоту можно и потом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать собственный фильтр.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:filterNotInCurrent "> ... </tr>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.values = function() {
    return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  };

  $scope.current = function() {
    return [3, 4];
  }

  $scope.filterNotInCurrent = function(item) {
    return ($scope.current().indexOf(item) == -1);
  };
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="app">
  <table data-ng-controller="Ctrl" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>$index</th>
        <th>Not in array</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="v in values() | filter:filterNotInCurrent ">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{v}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Но это не единственный вариант. Вам надо определиться с основным массивом данных. Нет ничего проще, чем показывать группу ввиде фильтра из основного массива.

Comment: О. Спасибо. Именно это я и хотел))